# Returning multiple lists in C#

Tags: c#, oop, list

I'm using a custom class to store information about files found in a directory based upon a regex, and I need to return these filelists from a method. Here's some psuedocode of how it's currently working:

```
class FileList {
//propertes of the file here, such as regex name, source folder and whether it needs to be deleted after copying
}

..
..

foreach (file in directory that matches regex)
{
    new filelist
    //Set all the properties
}

return allfilelists;
```

But how do I return the all the lists, or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not return a list of FileLists?

```
var allfilelists = new List<FileList >();
foreach (file in directory that matches regex)
{
    new filelist
    //Set all the properties
    allfilelists.Add(fileList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not to return a `List<FileList>` or something similar? (There's a choice of abstraction here - you could declare that the method returns `IEnumerable<FileList>`, `IList<FileList>`, `List<FileList>` etc.)

Comment: ... one notable difference being that `IEnumerable<FileList>` would communicate that the list is read-only, and possibly not yet fully in-memory ("lazy"). +1

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can return `IEnumerable<FileList>` on the method and use the `yield` keyword to use deferred execution and eliminate the overhead of the List object (as little as it is).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List<FileList>` or `FileList[]`.